# File transfer via ethernet cable

Tags: windows, ethernet, file-transfer

I have read that ethernet cable (normal, not cross-over) transfer is faster than normal USB transfer, and I'm trying to do just that – transferring from Windows 7 to Windows 8.

However, after turning on file sharing for both computers and connecting the cable, I can't seem to access files. I troubleshooted the ethernet connection, and it said that I have an invalid IP address.

- Windows 7 ethernet IP: 169.254.212.219
- Windows 8 ethernet IP: 169.254.95.183

Comment: Exactly how are each machine's IP setting set?  What are you doing to get the "Invalid IP address" message?  What exactly have you tried already in attempts to fix this?

Comment: Open run "Win" + "R" then type "ipconfig /release" on both your computers, see if it helps.

Comment: I think because it isn't connected, I can't release my ip.
"No operation can be performed on WI-FI while it has it's media disconnected. An error occurred while releasing interface Ethernet: an address has not yet been associated with the network endpoint"

Comment: Those are external ips. How are your computer connected? Connect your computers to each other via a switch or router, or a crossover cable.

Comment: @Martin I'm just using a normal ethernet cable, not a cross-over cable. But I've read it should work.

Comment: @Martin That command gets rid of any DHCP-assigned IP addresses, setting them to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: @Martin Those aren't external IPs, they are self-assigned (like those you get when you don't have a DHCP server or there is a problem auto-configuring)

Comment: @slhck My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost seems like you are getting APIPA addresses, but not correctly.

Manually set the IPs on the machines to 169.254.255.10 and .11 and you they should be able to communicate.

Comment: thanks! That worked for me, although I don't know why! Transfer speeds are around 68kb/s for me.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you use windows, try `\\{Computer name}` or `\\{local ip}`, i.e. `\\Foobar` or `\\10.0.0.26`, if you've turned on sharing no more hassle is necessary.
Whether the transfer speed is greater or not depends on a lot of factors, but if both computers are connected through gigabit cables, it'll usually be faster than usb 2.0.

Dunno why this has been downvoted, I regularly transfer files between my computers, using a gigabit switch, and files are transferred with a stable speed of +/- 80 MB/s, up to 125 MB/s when both computers used SSD's, using Windows shares.

Comment: Samba\Windows Shares are not very effective to copy files. FTP is a lot faster.

Comment: @edvinas.me I didnt comment either way on the effectiveness of windows shars/samba, but if the only thing OP has done is to turn on sharing in windows, that is how he can access those shares. There's no magic FTP connection, that has to be set up.